# Time interval overlaps - teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I need help with interval overplaps. I have these records in one table (and much more):

**Example 1:**

```
Id---------StartDate------EndDate

794122    2011-05-10    2999-12-31

794122    2011-04-15    2999-12-31

794122    2008-04-03    2999-12-31

794122    2008-03-31    2999-12-31

794122    2008-02-29    2999-12-31

794122    2008-02-04    2999-12-31

794122    2007-10-10    2999-12-31

794122    2007-09-15    2999-12-31
```

**Example 2:**

```
Id---------StartDate------EndDate

5448    2012-12-28      2999-12-31

5448    2011-06-30      2999-12-31

5448    2005-12-26      2011-06-30

5448    2005-06-15      2011-06-30

5448    2006-07-31      2006-12-31

5448    2001-03-31      2006-07-15
```

**Example 3:**

```
Id---------StartDate------EndDate

214577    2007-02-28    2999-12-31

214577    2003-06-20    2007-03-04

214577    2003-06-20    2007-02-28
```

**Example 4:**

```
Id---------StartDate-------EndDate

9999    2008-05-28      2999-01-01

9999    2005-03-03      2008-05-31

9999    2005-05-31      2005-12-31

9999    2003-12-01      2005-08-12

9999    2001-01-01      2002-03-05

9999    2000-01-08      2002-01-01
```

**I would like to get:**

```
*Example1* - 2007-09-15->3000-01-01

*Example2* - 2001-03-31->3000-01-01

*Example3* - 2003-06-20->3000-01-01

*Example4* - 2003-12-01->3000-01-01
```

Have you any suggestions how I do it? Because i dont choose max and min values(group by Id) -> This problem is in the example 4.

Thanks!

Comment: What is your question?  Can you show the results you want?

Comment: I would like to get these intervals for:

Example1 - 2007-09-15->3000-01-01

Example2 - 2001-03-31->3000-01-01

Example3 - 2003-06-20->3000-01-01

Example4 - 2003-12-01->3000-01-01 !!!

Comment: Is this a typo? {9999, 2008-05-28, 2999-01-01}

Comment: What's the logic for choosing a date in 2003 for the start date in example 4?

Comment: Sorry Mike, I had mistake in example 4. Now its ok. I want to uninterrupted interval.

Comment: Why isn't {9999, 2000-01-08, 2002-03-05} in the desired output? That seems to be an unterrupted interval.

Comment: No it isnt because: second row overlap first row -> new_value=2005-03-03->3000-12-31. Thirt row overlap a new_value -> new_value2 is same like new_value(because 2005-03-03 is min then 2005-05-31. Fourth row overlap newvalue2 -> new_valie3=2003-12-01->3000-12-31. And next two row isnt overlap new_value3.

Comment: In the absence of an explicit ORDER BY clause, there's no such thing as "first row" or "second row" in a SQL database. If you have to rely on the order of rows *without* an ORDER BY clause, I don't think what you want to do is possible.

Comment: Thanks I know, and I order by EndDate desc and StartDate desc, but I dont know how i choose an uninterrupted interval. These examples are sort.

Answer (score 2):

The result for example #4 doesn't match your data, shouldn't this be 9999, 2999-01-02 instead of 3000-01-01?

A typical solution for combining overlapping periods uses nested OLAP-functions, for your specific requirement (only the latest period) it can be a bit simplified to:

```
SELECT *
FROM
 (
   SELECT DISTINCT -- DISTINCT is not neccessary, but results in a better plan
      Id,
      StartDate,
      MAX(EndDate) 
      OVER (PARTITION BY Id) + 1 AS EndDate
   FROM dropme AS t
   QUALIFY -- find the gap
      COALESCE(StartDate 
               - MAX(EndDate) 
                 OVER (PARTITION BY Id
                       ORDER BY StartDate, EndDate
                       ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING), 1) > 0
 ) AS dt
QUALIFY 
   ROW_NUMBER() 
   OVER (PARTITION BY Id
         ORDER BY StartDate DESC) = 1
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to do this?

```
select id, min(start_date) as start_date, max(end_date) as end_date
from t
group by id;
```

EDIT:

Now that I understand what you need.  It identifies the rows that start a new period (using the `not exists` clause to look for overlaps).  It then chooses the maximum `start_date` among those rows for each id:

```
select t.id, min(t.start_date) as start_date, max(t.end_date) as end_date
from (select id, max(start_date) as maxsd
      from t
      where not exists (select 1
                        from t t2
                        where t2.start_date < t.start_date and
                              t2.end_date >= t.start_date
                       )
      group by id
     ) ids join
     t
     on t.id = ids.id and
        t.start_date >= maxsd
group by t.id;
```

The final step joins back to the original data and does the aggregation on anything that starts after the start date.

Comment: Thanks, but it is not working in example 4(I need 2003-12-01->3000-01-01)

Answer (score 0):

You want the end date to be the first day of the following year?

```
select id, min(startdate) start_date, 
       cast(max(extract(year from enddate)) + 1 || '-01-01' as date) end_date
from table1
group by id
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to uninterrupted interval. I always begin in max enddate and search it.